# Foreign key usage?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

To all the pros out there. I finally figure out the issue i am having and I have read the foreign key posts in the past but none answer the question i have. My knowledge of foreign key is to link 2 tables while 1 of the table has a pre stored input so the foreign key takes the pre stored input to link to the 2nd table. Now my question comes: Is there a way to use foreign key on new data? Such as using django form with 2 models. Lets say I have this page which is to add a totally new device (None of the 2 tables have any info on this new device). And when i key in the forms. I want to allow saving of the 1st model then pass on (lets say 1st model have the field of 'hostname' and 'ipaddr') 'hostname' to the 2nd table as foreign key so the rest of the fields( model 2) within the same form get saved. Is this possible?

I have my existing codes but it is not doing the above at all. It is currently registering the new device to a pre stored device at the moment and i dont know what how to change it as my knowledge of foreign key = need existing updates. I know how to do it if the page requires a login and sync the data to the log in user but this web doesnt require log in. Below are the codes:

views.py

```
def device_add(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    device_frm = DeviceForm(request.POST) ##Part A1
    dd_form = DeviceDetailForm(request.POST)
    if device_frm.is_valid():
        # Create and save the device
        # new_device here is the newly created Device object
        new_device = device_frm.save()

        if dd_form.is_valid():

            # Create an unsaved instance of device detail
            deviceD = dd_form.save(commit=False)

            # Set the device we just created above as this device detail's device
            deviceD.device = new_device

            # If you did not render the hostname for the device detail, set it from the value of new device
            deviceD.hostname = new_device.hostname
            deviceD.save()
        return render(request, 'interface/device_added.html',{'devices':device}) 

else:
    device_frm = DeviceForm()
    dd_form = DeviceDetailForm()
    di_frm = DeviceInterfaceForm()
    return render(request,'interface/device_add.html',{'form':device_frm, 'dd_form': dd_form})
```

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
        hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        ipaddr = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.hostname
    
  class DeviceDetail(models.Model):
            hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            mgt_interface = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            mgt_ip_addr = models.CharField(max_length=30)
            subnetmask = models.CharField(max_length=30)
            ssh_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            ssh_pwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            enable_secret = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            dev_mod = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            device_model = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            
            def __str__(self):
                return self.hostname
```

forms.py

```
class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Device
        fields= ['hostname', 'ipaddr'] 



 class DeviceDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= DeviceDetail
        fields= ['hostname', 'mgt_interface', 'mgt_ip_addr', 'subnetmask', 'ssh_id', 'ssh_pwd', 'enable_secret', 'dev_mod']

    def clean_hostname(self):
        hostname = self.cleaned_data['hostname']
        if len(hostname) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError(f'Hostname needs to be more than 8 character long, {hostname}')
        return hostname
```

More details in pic: So currently my form has Model: drop down box. This field is required to select a previous stored hostname to link this new device i registered. It is required as if i remove this, the form doesnt saved on the 2nd model: DeviceDetail. Currently this field appear due to the following codes in html: **This part is removed**

```
<div class="row">
                            

<div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="{{dd_form.dev_mod_id.id_for_label}}">Model<span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    {{dd_form.device_model}}

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[image]

What I want to do is to remove this field and let it do its work at the back. Such as when i load this page(form) it doesnt have this field and when i key in all the details and press save. At the code, it takes the hostname i input and pass it on to the foreign key (Currently it takes the pre stored hostname as the foreign key) then saved this new hostname and the other details in the 2nd table.

[image]

Below is for the database:
This is for device table once i add save new data
[image]

This is device detail table
[image]

Look at the value *11* beside the column with the input of *Catalyst 9606R*

This value 11 comes the id from the device table (Pre stored hostname)(This happens due to the module drop down box which appear in the form to ask me choose a previously stored hostname [image]

This is not i need. I need the new id which is **61** from the 3rd image

Comment: Can you describe how the models end up right now, and what you are expecting it to be? Like some sample data and the output you are getting, and what you want to get \

Comment: I just update the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to create both `Device` and `DeviceDetail` in one POST.

To support this, first remove `device_model` from the form and *don't render it* in your template (you don't have to, because we are putting a value for it later):

```py
class DeviceDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= DeviceDetail
        fields = [
            'hostname', 'mgt_interface', 'mgt_ip_addr', 'subnetmask', 
            'ssh_id', 'ssh_pwd', 'enable_secret'
        ] # Remove 'device_model'
```

Then in your views, save the device first. Then use that newly created device as foreign key of the device detail we are about to create:

```py
def device_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        device_frm = DeviceForm(request.POST)
        dd_form = DeviceDetailForm(request.POST)

        if device_frm.is_valid():

            # Create and save the device
            # new_device here is the newly created Device object
            new_device = device_frm.save()

            if dd_form.is_valid():

                # Create an unsaved instance of device detail
                deviceD = dd_form.save(commit=False)

                # Set the device we just created above as this device detail's device
                deviceD.device_model = new_device

                # If you did not render the hostname for the device detail, set it from the value of new device
                deviceD.hostname = new_device.hostname
                deviceD.save()
```

Comment: Yes that is what i want to do but I have the following error: NOT NULL constraint failed: interface_devicedetail.device_model_id. I tried removing this field before and I had the same error as this

Comment: Did you do this line: `deviceD.device = new_device`

Comment: Can you update your question with the **exact** code you are using right now?

Comment: Yes i did. I just deleted the device_module for forms.py and copy and paste for the views.py

Comment: I got a typo. Should be `deviceD.device_model = new_device`

Comment: Sorry just got a question. Whats the point of deviceD.hostname = new_device.hostname. Isnt the hostname automatically transfer over? Or is it because of the command deviceD=dd_form,save(commit=False) which result in the remaining fields being saved only and since hostname been used in device table it cannot be used again unless u assign it once more?

Comment: Yes you're right it should still be saved to device detail.